# Is it possible to change the urls.primaryName parameter name of Swagger UI?

Tags: .net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm developing an API with .NET 7, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and Swagger. The API has two definitions, as shown in the image below:

[image: Swagger definitions]

When changing from one setting to another, the Swagger UI URL looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44369/index.html?urls.primaryName=swagger-pt
```

Is it possible to change the name of the parameter "urls.primaryName", so that the URL looks like this?

```
https://localhost:44369/index.html?v=swagger-pt
```

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore? Or some other library?

Comment: @Helen I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Comment: You'll probably have to fork [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), rename `urls.primaryName` to `v` [in the source code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/search?q=primaryname), and configure Swashbuckle to use your custom Swagger UI fork instead of the bundled version.